# When rewriting core methods, in some cases method works just as it worked before rewritten

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
class Humanoid
  def something
    return 123
  end
  def to_s
    puts "I am new person now, please let's have a fresh start!"
  end
end

mermaid = Humanoid.new
```

This code:

```
p mermaid.to_s
```

outputs:

```
I am new person now, please let's have a fresh start!
```

but this:

```
p mermaid.something.to_s
```

gave me this output:

```
"123"
```

When I call this rewritten method directly, it runs the code that I wrote, whereas when I chain it as in the second way, it works just as the original method would. Can someone give an explanation on how and what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`something` returns the `Fixnum` instance `123`, and `Fixnum#to_s` (not the one you defined) converts that to a `String` instance `"123"`, which is inspected by `p`.

Comment: That is clear. But why is to_s working as original method again after I rewritten it?

Comment: You are defining `Humanoid#to_s`, which is irrelevant to `Fixnum`.

Comment: So that means that the method that I chained second doesn't actually refer to the object `mermaid`, but to the value returned with `something` method?

Comment: That is always the case with Ruby.

Comment: Kunok, when you have `mermaid.something.to_s`, Ruby first executes `mermaid.something`. Many classes may have a method `something`, so how does Ruby decide which to use? Ruby *sends* the method `something` to its *receiver*, `mermaid`, but `mermaid` only responds to its classes' instance methods (defined by `Humanoid` or one of its ancestors).  So it's `Humanoid#something`: `mermaid.something #=> 123`. Next, Ruby evaluates `123.to_s #=> "123"`, using `Fixnum#to_s`, since `123.class #=> Fixnum`. (`mermaid` also responds to its *singleton* methods, but that's a lesson for another day.)